# how can we use onbefoerunload in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I am creating a function that prevent the user when he reload the page or press a back space or press back button of Browser . i try the following code..

```
$wnd.beforeunload=function()
 {
    return "hello";
 }
```

it is working with simply java script but not in jsni . i also used

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event)
    {
        event.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    }
});
```

this is working with page refreh and closing, but not working with back button of browser and backspace ...pleace HELP..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already posted an answer in the same context.

> Please have a look at [promt user on backspace and browser backbutton in gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291882/promt-user-on-backspace-and-browser-backbutton-in-gwt?answertab=votes#tab-top) for complete code with screenshots.

Try with any option:

- `History.addValueChangeHandler`
- `WindowClosingHandler`
- `Event.addNativePreviewHandler`
- `$wnd.onbeforeunload`

Comment: Braj I try this, but it is not working on back button of browser . is there any possible method that prompt user on back button just like a closing handler ?

Comment: onkeydown working in both FF and chrome but in FF event.cancle is not working

Comment: @user3364549 Thanks a lot. I have just modified my post. Please have a look. I am still working on Back button of Browser. I'll come back with some solution.

Comment: there is a probleam its not working in devlopment mode but work on tomcat .

Comment: Thanks a lot again for all your findings.

Comment: @user3364549 I noticed one thing. can you tell me what is the difference between `$wnd.onbeforeunload` and `$wnd.beforeunload`?

Comment: onunload is responsible for executing an instruction when the page is closed. It also causes issue with IE and AJAX.

onbeforeunload is more efficient because it does not run in competition with the actual closing of the window and is triggered before onunload

I know Opera used to not acknowledge onbeforeunload - not sure if they've fixed that, but I always register the listener for both to be safe: