# prompt user on backspace and browser backbutton in gwt

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have two classes when navigating from one class to another created history. Now, I want to prompt the user by a confirm whether user wants to leave the page or not.Till now , I tried using `Window.closingHandler()` in `gwt` but its not working for backspace button and browser back button its only working on closing the entire browser or that particular page using cross. Its also working on reload.

I have also tried on Javascript and it worked perfect using `onbeforeunload()`.

Here are the codes I used.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  return "Are you sure you wish to leave this delightful page?";
}
```

And the other code in gwt:

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
    public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
        event.setMessage("Do you wanna close?");
        System.out.println("Closing...");
    }
});
```

I want it to be done in `gwt`.

Comment: the onbeforeunload() is not working on jsni i tried it too...

Comment: seraching for such function in gwt

Comment: Since you're not leaving your app when using "back" `onbeforeunload` doesn't fire. One alternative would be to listen for a `History` change event in this case.

Comment: its working on html pages but not in gwt project. itried to get it on valuechangehandler() but i cant get the prompt there.

Comment: i got a problem with it as its working twice when i called that class and when i changed the history by clicking on browserback button

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/aMDOTYGS1D0) might be relevant as well.

Comment: Have you tried overriding onStop() in activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got this in JSNI, But its also not working in browser back button..

```
public native void call()/*-{

    $wnd.onkeypress = GetChar;

     function GetChar (event)
     {
        var key = event.keyCode;

        var bb = event.target.nodeName;

             if(key==8 && bb=="BODY")
                {
                    var x= window.confirm("Are you sureyou want to leave the page");

                    if (x==true)
                            {
                                window.history.back();
                            }
                    else if(x==false)
                            {

                                return false;
                            }
                }
        }                   
}-*/;
```

Comment: onkeydown is working for both brewser but in FF on confirm cancle this call previous class ....?????????????/

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I have updated post where I have handled it for `browser back button` as well ad `backspace key` for all browsers.

Comment: No I haven't use this function. I have taken inputs from this link [how can we use onbefoerunload in GWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291626/how-can-we-use-onbefoerunload-in-gwt/23295079?noredirect=1#comment35685905_23295079) asked by @user3364549

Comment: I have chkd on opera and safari also working perfect

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `History.addValueChangeHandler` which listens for changes in the browser's history stack?

---

-- EDIT --

Below code is working fine for `Backspace key` in `Firefox`, `Chrome` as well as `IE9`.

Note: Please test it for other browsers also and let me know if there is any issue.

```
    Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onPreviewNativeEvent(final NativePreviewEvent event) {
            boolean isFirefox = checkBrowser("Firefox");
            if ((isFirefox && event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONKEYPRESS)
                    || (!isFirefox && event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONKEYDOWN)) {
                if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE) {
                    Element element = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());

                    String tagName = element.getTagName();

                    System.out.println(tagName);

                    if (!tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("INPUT")
                            && !tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("TEXTAREA")) {

                        boolean result = Window.confirm("Are you sure?");
                        if (!result) {
                            event.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if (checkBrowser("Firefox")) {
        DOM.sinkEvents(RootPanel.get().getElement(), Event.ONKEYPRESS);
    } else {
        DOM.sinkEvents(RootPanel.get().getElement(), Event.ONKEYDOWN);
    }

....

private static boolean checkBrowser(String browserName) {
    return (Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().toLowerCase().indexOf(browserName.toLowerCase()) != -1);
}
```

-- EDIT --

Here is the code detect browser Back button also. For more info have a look at

> [How to know whether refresh button or browser back button is clicked in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457797/how-to-know-whether-refresh-button-or-browser-back-button-is-clicked-in-firefox)

```
public native void onBeforeUnload()/*-{

    $wnd.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        return 'Are you sure?';
    };
}-*/;

public void onModuleLoad() {

    onBeforeUnload();

}
```

screenshots (browser back button is clicked or page is refreshed)

[image]

[image]
[image]

Please have a look at below posts:

- [GWT back button browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797907/gwt-back-button-browser)
- [Best way to detect browser closing/navigation to other page and do logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888483/best-way-to-detect-browser-closing-navigation-to-other-page-and-do-logout)

Comment: yes, i tried History.addValueChangeHandler but its not working , i told u that its working twice when the first time the class is called and during the change of history also.

Comment: braj still its not working for browser back button . otherwise ur code is useful. jst like this i tried it with jsni also.

Comment: on constructor of class. now , i have one more question for u, how to run gwt without plugin on safari and opera browser

Comment: As now i am  facing browser compatibility problem

Comment: You need plugin only for dev mode. Deploy your war on tomcat or any other server and test it in any browser.

Comment: we have already worked on the same function but in jsni its not working and perfectly working in simple javascript for html pages. see the first example of my ques its the same.

Comment: I have tried it in Firefox, Chrome as well as IE9. Its working fine for me when back button is clicked or page is refreshed. Please have a look at my last edit section.

Comment: Its `$wnd.onbeforeunload` not `window.onbeforeunload` in GWT JSNI.

Comment: In what browser are you testing it?

Comment: actually its working when we close the particular page from browser but not on its back button plz re-chk

Comment: Please tell me on which browser are you working so that I can test it.